# What is the best way to hide a specific user from a table in Laravel 4 ?

Tags: html, mysql, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I wish to know the best way to hide a specific user from a table ?

In my case, I want to hide the user that is no longer active.

**Query in Controller**

```
$users = User::where('id', '!=', '#id of disabled user')->get();
```

**View**

```
@foreach ($users as $user)

// print the table 

@endforeach
```

Am I close at all ?

[image: Sample Image]

Comment: think about second user, which becomes inactive one moment... Use `not in` sql statement should be better.. `User::select(..)->whereNotIn('id', [1])`

Comment: I'm a bit confused by the image you added. What do you mean by hide? Don't show at all or display with a different style (greyed out in the image)?

Comment: What do you define as in active? You can use soft deleting to 'delete' the user (not actually deleting from the db, but rather setting up a `deleted_at` flag). Then when you say `User::all()`, only the undeleted users show up. You can always use `withTrash()`, or `onlyTrash()` to see deleted users as well as `restore()` to undelete them.

Comment: Sure. I can define active. In my db, in users table, active is an  attribute of a user. I set active = 0 (pending), active = 1(active), and active = 2 (disabled). I want to hide all the users where active = 2. I hope this is precise enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a "normal" where statement

```
$users = User::where('active', '!=', 2)->get();
```

Comment: Is it the only way to do this ?

Comment: No it is certainly not. But from what I know about your application it seemed like the best. Is there anything you don't like about it?